# Get data from asp.net page using curl

Tags: php, asp.net, curl, web-scraping

I tried `file_get_content` and curl to get page data that shows when I open it in browser but get nothing.

URL opens in browser but when I use curl I redirected to home page, what method I use to complete grab page with all data in my response.

```
    function curl($url)
    {
      $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0";
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
      $data = curl_exec($ch);
      $info = curl_getinfo($ch);  
      print_r($info);
      echo "curl error".curl_error($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      echo $data;
      return $data;
    }

    $secState = '70';
    $rankYear = 2013;
    $url = 'https://tennislink.usta.com/tournaments/rankings/rankinghome.aspx#Action=1&SectionDistrict='.$secState.'&Year='.$rankYear.'&Division=G8&ListType=0';
    echo $url;
    $html=curl($url);
    echo $html;
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure, your url is correct? there's an whitesapce char between `&` and `SectionDistrict`

You can try it again with the following

```
    $url = 'https://tennislink.usta.com/tournaments/rankings/rankinghome.aspx#Action=1&SectionDistrict='.$secState.'&Year='.$rankYear.'&Division=G8&ListType=0';
```

This url should also work with `file_get_contents`

Comment: No, actually i was formatting question here @Stackoverflow and it's just a formatting error, in the actual code there is no error.
Site is is in ASP.net and doing _dopostback to get content and i think there is some problem, i can't getting data because of javascript dopostback function.
i don't know how to fix that problem.

Comment: If the data is pulled with ajax, you could use the DeveloperTools of your browser and monitor the send data to determine the correct url, method and params. In your case, you have to send a POST request and add a lot of data. Perhabs, you have to parse the content of `https://tennislink.usta.com/tournaments/rankings/rankinghome.aspx` to add all necessary hidden filds for the post request